Consecutive sequence in SQL
enter image description hereI have a columns similar the one shown below;-
Col1
------------
x1
x2,x3
x1,y5
y3,x5,x6
y6,y10,y11
x7,y8
y6,y9
;

I want to filter out only the rows that have at least 2 consecutive ones irrespective of the prefix alphabet. Rows 2,4,5 and 6 should be returned as a result.
I am trying to use SQL from another platform where replace function doesn't work. I was trying to remove text, then place numbers in different columns and compare among them to find consecutive numbers - like COl2 - Col1 if is 1 then true.

Please show the actual data, and are you really storing CSV numbers this way?

I just added the screenshot

if its a one to many relationship you can leverage window function that supported by most modern relational sql engine. a "flat form" like this you will have to use string functions which heavily dependent on the sql engine. so, what is your dbms?

which database are you using/writing the query for?

Are you limited to plain sql? A stored function could do the job...

Those type query (string manipulation) syntax quite specific to DBMS. You must specify the database you are using.

Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

hover over the tag "sql", it tells you this Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead.

Dear All, for the delay, this is in the sisense -https://www.sisense.com (sisense embedded in client's tool)

Sisense lets you connect with your data, wherever it may be ...  -which DBMS are you connecting to?
